# Code converter pascal to java or c++ or c

Tags: java, c++, c

I have a code written in Pascal but because I am not familiar with this language I am searching to find same converter to change it in java or c++ or c. Does anyone have same idea in order to make it possible to do that change?

Comment: Did you have a look at the program p2c as suggested in the answer of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373935/pascal-to-c-converter, link is not reachable anymore but searching for "p2c pascal to c translation"  or "p2c pascal to c converter" might give some hints.

Comment: For dead links, the WayBack Machine at https://archive.org/web/ ha a copy of just about every webpage ever published.